# Unable to read/bind configuration settings with strongly-typed class using Named Options in Asp.Net Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I am unable to bind configuration settings inside my appsettings.json to a strongly-types class using named options.

appsettings.json

```
"CJSettings": {
    "Normal": {
      "CSSUrl": "https://css.mydomain.com/main.min.css",
      "LogoName": "mysite-logo.png"
    },
    "WL": {
      "CSSUrl": "https://css.mydomain.com/main_wl.min.css",
      "LogoName": "mysite-WL-logo.png"
    },
    "SEG": {
      "CSSUrl": "https://css.mydomain.com/main_seg.min.css",
      "LogoName": "mysite-seg-logo.png"
    }}
```

CJSettings.cs

```
public class CJSettings
{
    public string CSSUrl { get; set; }
    public string LogoName { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<CJSettings>("Normal", configuration.GetSection("CJSettings.Normal"));
services.Configure<CJSettings>("WL", configuration.GetSection("CJSettings.WL"));
services.Configure<CJSettings>("SEG", configuration.GetSection("CJSettings.SEG"));
```

NormalService.cs

My service where i am trying to read configuration data using name. but no success.

```
public class NormalService : INormalService
{
    private readonly CJSettings cjSettings;

    public NormalService(IOptionsMonitor<CJSettings> options)
    {
        this.cjSettings = options.Get("Normal");    //getting null values for both properties
    }
}
```

As you can see above, i tried reading data using name "Normal" but i am getting null values for both properties of CJSettings object.

[image: named-options-read-null]

please help me to fix this... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your code is not working. I can suggest the following solution that I'm always using:

```
public class CJSettings
{
    public UrlSettings Normal { get; set; }
    public UrlSettings WL { get; set; }
    public UrlSettings SEG { get; set; }
}

public class UrlSettings
{
    public string CSSUrl { get; set; }
    public string LogoName { get; set; }
}
```

Register options and services:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CJSettings>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(CJSettings)));
        services.AddTransient<INormalService, NormalService>();

        // the rest of your code
    }
```

Then inject options into a constructor of your service:

```
public class NormalService : INormalService
{
    private readonly CJSettings cjSettings;

    public NormalService(IOptions<CJSettings> options)
    {
        this.cjSettings = options.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(CJSettings));
    }
}
```

This should work. I checked it out.

**UPDATED**

Actually your code is OK. You just need to use colons instead of dots in a key parameter of `GetSection` method:

```
services.Configure<CJSettings>("Normal", Configuration.GetSection("CJSettings:Normal"));
services.Configure<CJSettings>("WL", Configuration.GetSection("CJSettings:WL"));
services.Configure<CJSettings>("SEG", Configuration.GetSection("CJSettings:SEG"));
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what i missed. I never noticed that i was using dot instead. Thanks mcuh @Dmitry for help. :)